# Partial Zilog Z80 emulator written in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, emulator

> Followed-up [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/233431/less-incomplete-z80-emulator-written-in-c).

I've written a partial z80 emulator in C++. It has a decent part of the instructions that can be reused implemented but I've had some issues with duplicated code.

I'd also like to note that this is my first C++ project; before that I've primarily dealt with C and Assembly.

`emulate.cpp`:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include "z80emu.hpp"
#include "opcodes.h"

#ifndef NDEBUG
# include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#endif

namespace z80emu {
    // return value: number of instructions executed
    uint16_t z80::emulate()
    {
        reg *rp[] =
        {
            &regs.bc,
            &regs.de,
            &regs.hl,
            &regs.sp
        };
        reg *rp2[] =
        {
            &regs.bc,
            &regs.de,
            &regs.hl,
            &regs.af
        };
        uint16_t inst = 0;

        for(;;)
        {
            switch(mem[regs.pc])
            {
                case NOP:
                    break;
                case LD_BC_IMM:
                case LD_DE_IMM:
                case LD_HL_IMM:
                case LD_SP_IMM:
                    ld16imm(mem[regs.pc] >> 4, rp);
                    break;
                case LD_DBC_A:
                case LD_DDE_A:
                    deref16_u8(mem[regs.pc] >> 4, rp) = regs.af.high;
                    break;
                case INC_BC:
                case INC_DE:
                case INC_HL:
                case INC_SP:
                    inc16(mem[regs.pc] >> 4, rp);
                    break;
                case DEC_BC:
                case DEC_DE:
                case DEC_HL:
                case DEC_SP:
                    dec16(mem[regs.pc] >> 4, rp);
                    break;
                case INC_B:
                case INC_C:
                case INC_D:
                case INC_E:
                case INC_H:
                case INC_L:
                    inc8(mem[regs.pc], rp);
                    break;
                case DEC_B:
                case DEC_C:
                case DEC_D:
                case DEC_E:
                case DEC_H:
                case DEC_L:
                    dec8(mem[regs.pc], rp);
                    break;
                case LD_B_IMM:
                case LD_C_IMM:
                case LD_D_IMM:
                case LD_E_IMM:
                case LD_H_IMM:
                case LD_L_IMM:
                    ld8imm(mem[regs.pc], rp);
                    break;
                case RRCA:
                    rrc8(mem[regs.pc], rp);
                    break;
                case EX_AF_AF:
                    regs.af.exchange();
                    break;
                case ADD_HL_BC:
                case ADD_HL_DE:
                case ADD_HL_HL:
                case ADD_HL_SP:
                    regs.hl.combined += rp[mem[regs.pc] >> 4]->combined;
                    regs.hl.uncombine();
                    break;
                case LD_A_DBC:
                case LD_A_DDE:
                    regs.af.high = deref16_u8(mem[regs.pc] >> 4, rp);
                    regs.af.combine();
                    break;
                default:
#ifndef NDEBUG
                    cout << std::hex << std::showbase
                         << "af: " << regs.af.combined << endl
                         << "af': " << regs.af.exx << endl
                         << "bc: " << regs.bc.combined << endl
                         << "bc': " << regs.bc.exx << endl
                         << "de: " << regs.de.combined << endl
                         << "de': " << regs.de.exx << endl
                         << "hl: " << regs.hl.combined << endl
                         << "hl': " << regs.hl.exx << endl
                         << "sp: " << regs.sp.combined << endl
                         << "a: " << +regs.af.high << endl
                         << "f: " << +regs.af.low << endl
                         << "b: " << +regs.bc.high << endl
                         << "c: " << +regs.bc.low << endl
                         << "d: " << +regs.de.high << endl
                         << "e: " << +regs.de.low << endl
                         << "h: " << +regs.hl.high << endl
                         << "l: " << +regs.hl.low << endl;
#endif
                    throw std::logic_error("Unimplemented opcode!");
            }
            regs.pc++;
            inst++;
        }
        return inst;
    }
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include "z80emu.hpp"

void usage(const char *prog_name);

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    z80emu::z80 z80;
    std::ifstream infile;
    uint16_t file_size;

    if((unsigned)argc - 2 > 0)
    {
         usage(argv[0]);
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    infile.open(argv[1], std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary);
    if(!infile.good())
    {
        std::cerr << "Opening " << argv[1] << " failed: "
                  << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    }

    file_size = infile.seekg(0, infile.end).tellg();
    infile.seekg(0, infile.beg);

    infile.read((char *)z80.mem, file_size);

    try {
        z80.emulate();
    } catch(std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << "Emulation failed: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return 0;
}

void usage(const char *progname)
{
    std::cout << "  Usage: " << progname << " z80-prog" << std::endl;
}
```

`opcodes.h`:

```
#ifndef Z80EMU_OPCODES_H
#define Z80EMU_OPCODES_H 1

#define NOP     0x00
#define LD_BC_IMM   0x01
#define LD_DBC_A    0x02
#define INC_BC      0x03
#define INC_B       0x04
#define DEC_B       0x05
#define LD_B_IMM    0x06
#define RLCA        0x07
#define EX_AF_AF    0x08
#define ADD_HL_BC   0x09
#define LD_A_DBC    0x0a
#define DEC_BC      0x0b
#define INC_C       0x0c
#define DEC_C       0x0d
#define LD_C_IMM    0x0e
#define RRCA        0x0f
#define DJNZ_IMM    0x10
#define LD_DE_IMM   0x11
#define LD_DDE_A    0x12
#define INC_DE      0x13
#define INC_D       0x14
#define DEC_D       0x15
#define LD_D_IMM    0x16
#define RLA     0x17
#define JR_IMM      0x18
#define ADD_HL_DE   0x19
#define LD_A_DDE    0x1a
#define DEC_DE      0x1b
#define INC_E       0x1c
#define DEC_E       0x1d
#define LD_E_IMM    0x1e
#define RRA     0x1f
#define JR_NZ_IMM   0x20
#define LD_HL_IMM   0x21
#define LD_DIMM_HL  0x22
#define INC_HL      0x23
#define INC_H       0x24
#define DEC_H       0x25
#define LD_H_IMM    0x26
#define DAA     0x27
#define JR_Z_IMM    0x28
#define ADD_HL_HL   0x29
#define LD_HL_DIMM  0x2a
#define DEC_HL      0x2b
#define INC_L       0x2c
#define DEC_L       0x2d
#define LD_L_IMM    0x2e
#define CPL     0x2f
#define JR_NC_IMM   0x30
#define LD_SP_IMM   0x31
#define LD_DIMM_A   0x32
#define INC_SP      0x33
#define INC_DHL     0x34
#define DEC_DHL     0x35
#define LD_DHL_IMM  0x36
#define SCF     0x37
#define JR_C_IMM    0x38
#define ADD_HL_SP   0x39
#define LD_A_DIMM   0x3a
#define DEC_SP      0x3b
#define INC_A       0x3c
#define DEC_A       0x3d
#define LD_A_IMM    0x3e
#define CCF     0x3f

#endif
```

`tools.cpp`:

```
#include "z80emu.hpp"

namespace z80emu
{
    // return reference to 8-bit register or memory location
    uint8_t &z80::ref8(uint8_t idx, bool low, reg **tab)
    {
        // idx is the index for the 16-bit register (usually op >> 4)

        // if low is true, return the low part of the variable,
        // otherwise return the high part (usually !!(op & 8))

        switch(idx & 3)
        {
            case 3:
                return low ? regs.af.high : mem[regs.hl.combined];
            default:
                return low ? tab[idx]->low : tab[idx]->high;
        }
    }

    // return reference to a byte in memory
    // specified by a 16-bit pointer
    uint8_t &z80::deref16_u8(uint8_t idx, reg **tab)
    {
        return mem[tab[idx]->combined];
    }

    // load 16-bit register with immediate
    void z80::ld16imm(uint8_t idx, reg **tab)
    {
        // Do these individually because
        // of endianness and memory wrapping
        tab[idx]->low = mem[++regs.pc];
        tab[idx]->high = mem[++regs.pc];
        tab[idx]->combine();
    }

    // load 8-bit register with immediate
    void z80::ld8imm(uint8_t op, reg **tab)
    {
        uint8_t idx = op >> 4;
        ref8(idx, !!(op & 8), tab) = mem[++regs.pc];
        if((idx & 3) != 3) tab[idx]->combine();
        else if(op & 8) regs.af.combine();
    }

    // increment 16-bit register
    void z80::inc16(uint8_t idx, reg **tab)
    {
        tab[idx]->combined++;
        tab[idx]->uncombine();
    }

    // decrement 16-bit register
    void z80::dec16(uint8_t idx, reg **tab)
    {
        tab[idx]->combined--;
        tab[idx]->uncombine();
    }

    // add number to 8-bit register
    void z80::add8(uint8_t op, reg **tab, uint8_t incr)
    {
        uint8_t idx = op >> 4;
        ref8(idx, !!(op & 8), tab) += incr;
        if((idx & 3) != 3) tab[idx]->combine();
        else if(op & 8) regs.af.combine();
    }

    // increment 8-bit register
    void z80::inc8(uint8_t op, reg **tab)
    {
        add8(op, tab, 1);
    }

    // decrement 8-bit register
    void z80::dec8(uint8_t op, reg **tab)
    {
        add8(op, tab, -1);
    }

    void z80::rrc8(uint8_t op, reg **tab)
    {
        uint8_t idx = (op & 0x7) >> 1;
        uint8_t &ref = ref8(idx, op & 1, tab);
        ref = ref >> 1 | (ref & 1) << 7;
        if((idx & 3) != 3) tab[idx]->combine();
        else if((op & 0x7) == 0x7) regs.af.combine();
    }
}
```

`z80emu.hpp`:

```
#ifndef Z80EMU_HPP
#define Z80EMU_HPP 1

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
# include <cstdint>
# include <utility>
using std::uint16_t;
using std::uint8_t;
#else
# include <stdint.h>
# include <algorithm>
#endif

#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

// TODO: Decide whether to use struct or class

namespace z80emu
{
    enum cc
    {
        NZ = 0,
        Z  = 1,
        NC = 2,
        C  = 3,
        PO = 4,
        PE = 5,
        P  = 6,
        M  = 7
    };

    struct reg
    {
        uint8_t high, low;
        uint16_t combined, exx;

        void combine()
        {
            combined = high << 8 | low;
        }
        void uncombine()
        {
            high = combined >> 8;
            low = combined;
        }
        void exchange()
        {
            std::swap(combined, exx);
            uncombine();
        }
    };

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
    static_assert(sizeof(reg) == 6, "sizeof(reg) != 6");
#endif

    struct registers
    {
        reg af;
        reg bc;
        reg de;
        reg hl;
        reg ix;
        reg iy;
        reg sp;
        reg wz;
        uint16_t pc;
    };

    struct z80
    {
        uint8_t *mem;
        registers regs;

        uint16_t emulate();
        uint8_t &ref8(uint8_t op, bool low, reg **tab);
        uint8_t &deref16_u8(uint8_t op, reg **tab);
        void ld16imm(uint8_t op, reg **tab);
        void ld8imm(uint8_t op, reg **tab);
        void inc16(uint8_t op, reg **tab);
        void dec16(uint8_t op, reg **tab);
        void add8(uint8_t op, reg **tab, uint8_t incr);
        void inc8(uint8_t op, reg **tab);
        void dec8(uint8_t op, reg **tab);
        void rrc8(uint8_t op, reg **tab);

        z80()
        {
            mem = new uint8_t[0xffff];
        }

        ~z80()
        {
            delete[] mem;
        }
    };
}

#endif
```

Shell script to create example program (filename `test`) that will cause the program built with the modified version of `emulate.cpp` to print the registers on exit:

```
#!/bin/sh

printf '\001\275\274\021\337\336\041\316\315\061\255\336\377' > test
```

I'd like to note that later on in the implementation (when I get 15/16ths of it done), `rp2` will be used for `push` and `pop` so the `af` register (accumulator and flags) can be saved.

And, for the instructions I do have implemented, everything seems to be working fine (as in, the register values seem to be correct when I use `gdb` and `std::cout`).

What I'm mainly interested in:

- Are there any "more C++" things (that work from c++98 to c++2a) that I can do?  Have I started using the language's featured adequately?
- Can I reduce code duplication? Most of the functions in `tools.cpp` have to call `uncombine` or `combine` after altering the registers. Is there a way around this? What about with the `rrc8` function?
- Are there any C++ "best practices" that I'm missing here?
- If there are any other miscellaneous things that could be improved, please let me know, although I would appreciate it if you could focus on the other points more.

Comment: I would suggest that in order to get better  reviews, you include a sample file that your program can emulate.

Comment: @tinstaafl I can do that, but it won't be able to do much other than modify the registers. I'll go ahead and add a version of `emulate.cpp` that prints the registers, too.

Comment: That's fine.  It's mainly so reviewers can step through your code.

Comment: @tinstaafl Done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few quick observations:

1. Don't use `#define` for all those compile time constants (opcodes).  They should be part of an opcode `enum` or declared as `constexpr int`.
2. You're only allocating 65,535 bytes for `mem`, when you should be allocating 65,536.  An attempt to access `mem[0xFFFF]` will result in Undefined Behavior because it is past the end of the allocated space.
3. Having a default case label to catch unimplemented opcodes is a Good Thing.
4. `if((unsigned)argc - 2 > 0)` is somewhat obscure.  What's wrong with `if (argc != 2)`?
5. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with your `reg` struct, but you could eliminate the duplicate data storage to add byte and word accessor methods.  Both GCC and Clang will optimize (`-O3`) these to single instruction byte accesses.  MSVC does the same for getters, but setters are not fully optimized (with `/O2` and variations I tried).

   ```
   struct reg {
       uint16_t combined;
       uint8_t high() const
       {
           return combined >> 8;
       }
       uint8_t low() const
       {
           return combined & 255;
       }
       void seth(uint8_t v)
       {
           combined = (combined & 255) | (v << 8);
       }
       void setl(uint8_t v)
       {
           combined = (combined & ~255) | v;
       }
   };
   ```

   `combined` could be made private and accessors added to it if desired.
6. While it is unlikely a `z80` object will be copied, you should `=delete` the copy and move constructors and assignment operators.  See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Uhh... What does point 6 mean? I think you should see the [tag:beginner] tag. I'm also slightly confused by what `constexpr int` is.

Comment: Ah, I should've mentioned that I wanted this to be portable.

Comment: To get away from `combine()`/`uncombine()`, it might be best to give `reg` some member functions to read/write individual registers in the pair.

Comment: @TobySpeight After marinating on this overnight, I had similar thoughts and updated my answer to use member functions instead of punning with a union.

Comment: Do you mind if I show my changes so far to be reviewed? I've addressed most, if not all of your points.

Comment: @JL2210 If you've made changes to the code that you want reviewed, they should be posted as a follow on question.

Comment: Here's the follow-up: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/233431/less-incomplete-z80-emulator-written-in-c